# Conveying "How come...?" (expressing complain)

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

Deepl/Google Translate convey *how come* idiom in questions expressing complain like

> *How come* nobody's ever on time to meetings?

as

> Comment se fait-il que personne ne soit jamais à l'heure aux réunions ?

To my non-native ears it sounds a little formal with the inversion and the subjonctive. What other turns exist to convey the same meaning in a less formal way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one that comes to my mind (apart from "*pourquoi*") is:

> **Comment ça se fait que** [...] ?

It's the non-inverted version of "*comment se fait-il*" and that makes it way more informal. I don't think the subjonctive is a problem here.

You can use a lot of variations that can slightly change the meaning, such as:

- *Comment expliquer que [...]*
- *Qu'est-ce que qui fait que [...]* (this one, you use the present tense after, but it sounds a bit heavy in my point of view)
- *Pourquoi [...]* (which is just "why" so it doesn't convey the meaning of trying to explain the "how" precisely).
- *Comment est-ce possible que [...]* / *Comment c'est possible que [...]* (more informal)

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

True, it is a bit formal, but correct.

As a native-French, I would instead probably say

> Comment se fait-il que personne ne soit jamais à l'heure aux réunions ?

You could simply say (a bit familiar, not written French)

> Comment ça se fait que personne ne soit jamais à l'heure ? (aux réunions)
>   or
>   Comment est-ce possible que jamais personne n'est à l'heure aux réunions ?